# Allocation of Memory with python to pass to dll

Tags: python, c, pointers, memory, dll

I got a dll which expects a memory pointer to a C Type Byte Array. The dll will read and modify the Array and will also put some extra data at the end of the array.

How do I allocate 1MB memory as C Type Byte Array in python and get the pointer?

How can I write my C Type Byte Array in python to this pointer?

You are perhaps wondering why I want to do it this way, but this is unfortunately the only interface to this dll :/ and I have to do this in python.

Here is my current setup:

```
import ctypes

# Allocate Memory:
BUFFER_LENGTH = 20

# parse to pointer:
bytes_buffer = bytes([0x13, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x08, 0xA5]) # dummy data

size_in = len(bytes_buffer)
print(bytes_buffer)
# write binary data to memory in CTypes Byte Array
buffer_in = ctypes.cast(bytes_buffer, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char*BUFFER_LENGTH) )
adr = ctypes.pointer(buffer_in)
address = id(adr)

# get pointer as int32
pointer_data_hi = ctypes.c_uint32(address) 
pointer_data_lo = ctypes.c_uint32(address >> 32) 
print("in: hi: " + str(pointer_data_hi.value) + ", lo: " + str(pointer_data_lo.value) + ", size: " + str(size_in))

# Load dll
array_modifier = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("PythonArrayToDll/modify_array_example/x64/Debug/modify_array_example.dll")

# set pointer of array to dll memory:
array_modifier.setAddrLo(pointer_data_lo)
array_modifier.setAddrHi(pointer_data_hi)

# tell the dll to compute something from the data array:
array_modifier.modifyArray() # this is where it crashes with exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF


# display the results:
for i in range(BUFFER_LENGTH):
    print(buffer_in[i].value)
```

dll code (example):

```
#include <WinDef.h>
#include "pch.h"
#include "pointer_fnc.h"

#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

int addrHi;
int addrLo;

extern "C"
{

    DLL_EXPORT void setAddrLo(int lo)
    {
        addrLo = lo;
    }

    DLL_EXPORT void setAddrHi(int hi)
    {
        addrHi = hi;
    }

    DLL_EXPORT void modifyArray()
    {
        BYTE* my_array = (BYTE*)decode_integer_to_pointer(addrHi, addrLo);

        my_array[0] = my_array[0] * 2;
        my_array[1] = 2;
        my_array[10] = my_array[0];
    }
}
```

with pointer_fnc.cpp providing:

```
void* decode_integer_to_pointer(int hi, int lo)
{
#if PTRDIFF_MAX == INT64_MAX
    union addrconv {
        struct {
            int lo;
            int hi;
        } base;
        unsigned long long address;
    } myaddr;
    myaddr.base.lo = lo;
    myaddr.base.hi = hi;
    return reinterpret_cast<void*>(myaddr.address);
#elif PTRDIFF_MAX == INT32_MAX
    return reinterpret_cast<void*>(lo);
#else
#error "Cannot determine 32bit or 64bit environment!"
#endif
}
```

dll is compiled as a 64 bit and a 64 bit python is used.

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Please make sure to have a [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). General doc: [\[Python.Docs\]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes). An example: [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011).

Comment: @CristiFati I updated the example code. It should be a compilable, minimal example. Could you have a look at this problem, please?

Comment: Why 2 functions for *setAddr*? That makes things very complicated. Why not simply using a *void\**? *pointer\_fnc.cpp* would not be needed. There are more comments, but they don't fit here.

Comment: this is a simplification of an fmi2 interface. ( see fmi-standard.org). This interface doesn't allow pointers or int64. So someone invented a hack to pass a pointer by two int32. The goal is to transfer a grpc buffer with that pointer into the dll.

All I want now, is to use a dll with this interface with python.

I know this interface is far away from an optimal choice of design... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

**Issues**:

- I shallowly browsed [Functional Mock-up Interface](https://fmi-standard.org) , but I didn't see any reference to the *API*. Anyway, this *hi*, *lo* approach is poor (looks like it's from from the *16bit* (segment, offset) era). Pointers exist for decades, and that's precisely their purpose: handling memory addresses

  - There's no size limit ("how far can one go" from the (start) address), meaning that the *API* consumers might end up accessing memory that they don't own (***U**ndefined **B**ehavior* - very likely to crash)

  The above make me think there's a (big) misunderstanding about the *API*
- Don't mix *Python* and *CTypes* object addresses, they are not the same! [[Python.Docs]: Built-in Functions - id(object)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) returns the *Python* wrapper object (*PyObject*) address, not the actual pointer (that you care about)
- A very common one (missing functions *argtypes*, *restype*): [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011), but it's not affecting the current scenario
- Since you're on *Win*, take a look at [[MS.Docs]: ULARGE_INTEGER union (winnt.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-ularge_integer-r1), no need to reinvent the wheel. Anyway, I removed that to be as platform independent as possible
- Combining the 2 *int*s in a *unsigned long long* might have disastrous effects for a negative value (sign bit set) of *hi*
- More minor ones (that don't worth mentioning individually)

I prepared a small example.

*dll00.c*:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif

#define BYTE unsigned char


static uint32_t addrLo = 0;
static uint32_t addrHi = 0;


#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API void setAddrLo(int lo);
DLL00_EXPORT_API void setAddrHi(int hi);
DLL00_EXPORT_API void modifyArray();

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif


void setAddrLo(int lo) {
    addrLo = (uint32_t)lo;
}

void setAddrHi(int hi) {
    addrHi = (uint32_t)hi;
}

static BYTE* toPtr(uint32_t hi, uint32_t lo) {
#if SIZE_MAX == 0xffffffffffffffffull
    uint64_t quad = ((uint64_t)hi << 32) + lo;
    printf("C  - Addr: 0x%016llX, Hi: 0x%08X, Lo: 0x%08X\n", quad, hi, lo);
    return (BYTE*)quad;
#elif SIZE_MAX == 0xfffffffful
    printf("C  - Addr: 0x%016llX, Hi: 0x%08X, Lo: 0x%08X\n", lo, hi, lo);
    return (BYRE*)lo;
#else
#  error "Neither 64bit nor 32bit architecture"
#endif
}

void modifyArray() {  // A 'size' argument would be make sense to specify maximum array index.
    BYTE *addr = toPtr(addrHi, addrLo);
    if (addr == NULL) {
        printf("C  - NULL pointer!\n");
        return;
    }
    addr[0] *= 2;
    addr[1] = 2;
    addr[10] = addr[0];
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ctypes as ct


DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")
BUF_LEN = 20


def main(*argv):
    dll = ct.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
    set_addr_lo = dll.setAddrLo
    set_addr_lo.argtypes = (ct.c_int,)
    set_addr_lo.restype = None
    set_addr_hi = dll.setAddrHi
    set_addr_hi.argtypes = (ct.c_int,)
    set_addr_hi.restype = None
    modify_array = dll.modifyArray
    modify_array.argtypes = ()
    modify_array.restype = None

    b = b"\x20\x03\x20"
    Array = ct.c_char * BUF_LEN
    buf = Array(*b)
    print("PY - Array: {:}".format(list(ord(i) for i in buf)))
    addr = ct.addressof(buf)  # The reverse of what's done in the .dll (toPtr) - doesn't make much sense
    if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000:
        lo = addr & 0xffffffff
        hi = (addr >> 32) & 0xffffffff
    else:
        hi = 0
        lo = addr
    print("PY - Addr: 0x{:016X}, Hi: 0x{:08X}, Lo: 0x{:08X}".format(addr, hi, lo))
    set_addr_lo(lo)
    set_addr_hi(hi)
    modify_array()
    print("PY - Array: {:}".format(list(ord(i) for i in buf)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```batch
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q068304564]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 >nul
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll
> dll00.c
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.08.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> PY - Array: [32, 3, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
> PY - Addr: 0x00000203275B23B0, Hi: 0x00000203, Lo: 0x275B23B0
> C  - Addr: 0x00000203275B23B0, Hi: 0x00000203, Lo: 0x275B23B0
> PY - Array: [64, 2, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>
> Done.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the amazing answer! Was looking for an example like this. I would like to mention that had this warning while compiling dll00.c

```
format ‘%llX’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘uint64_t’
```

so I changed on line 42 0x%016llX to 0x%016lX. For sake of completeness if you are a newbie like me to generate the dll in linux you need to run the following commands

```
gcc -c -fpic dll00.c
gcc -shared -o libdll.so dll00.o
```